# Add SSL Certificate to Windows Docker Container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, ssl-certificate

How can I add a *.cer*-Certificate inside a Docker container? It has to be done via powershell since the container has no interface to open `mms.exe`.

[This](http://colmprunty1.azurewebsites.net/2017/06/07/import-and-bind-an-ssl-cert-in-windows-container/) is a good tutorial for *.pfx*-Certificates. Since I have a *.cer*-file without private key, I have to adapt it slightly.
The powershell command from the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848630.aspx)
`Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\myCertificateToAdd.cert -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root\` gets stuck whenever called.

Comment: define stuck? interactive container session or not?

Comment: I try it in an interactive container session and the powershell call just never returns.

Comment: try adding `-force`?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such parameter: "A parameter cannot be found, that matches parameter name 'force'"

Comment: Adding a `-type CERT` parameter as seen [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sonam_rastogi_blogs/2014/08/18/request-export-and-import-certificate-using-powershell/#comment-3475) does not help either.

Comment: @balujr. If you run that on your computer (not the container) are your prompted for anything or does it complete successfully?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem does not appear when importing to the LocalMachine folder:

`Import-Certificate -FilePath C:\myCertificateToAdd.cert -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root\`

Like this, the certificate is importet to every "CurrentUser" on the machine. If this is ok, as for the typical DockerContainer, the problem is solved.