# Docker Windows Container Load certificate from store of the host machine

Tags: c#, docker, ssl-certificate, windows-container

I am learning docker, have the below c# code which is trying to find a certificate from the  host machine based on the subject and attaches that certificate to the outgoing httprequest. This piece of code works fine outside docker. Published this project as an image from Visual studio and it is running in the windows container of docker desktop.
But within the Docker, certificates count is 0.

Where does the docker looks for the certificates? what is the Path.

How to make the code running in the container look for certificates in the windows host machine.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Container has its own certificate store. When you want to use a certificate from the host, you have to copy the certificate to the store into the container first explicitly according to [this blog post by Yash Chaubery](https://medium.com/@yash5044/configuring-windows-store-certificates-inside-docker-container-53c92b661db4).

Export the certificate from the store of the host into a file. Then copy the file to the Docker container and then use for example a PowerShell script to import the certificate into the store of the container as explained in [Add SSL Certificate to Windows Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480275/add-ssl-certificate-to-windows-docker-container)